# How can I disable the 'unmount' option for my second internal harddisk in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, user-interface, ubuntu-unity, unmount

**Edit: it seems that this is a known bug and that it is impossible.**

How can I disable the 'unmount' option for my second internal harddisk in Ubuntu?

My system consists of a 128GB SSD and a 1TB HDD.

The reason I want to disable this button is to prevent accidental clicks when I'm clicking the unmount buttons for USB sticks that I'm unmounting.

There is absolutely no reason for me to unmount this internal HDD, yet I still see the 'unmount' button (underlined triangle) in my Unity filebrowser side pane.

[image]

Here is a snippet of my /etc/fstab:

```
# <file system>                              <mnt>           <type>    <options>                               <dump>    <pass>
/dev/mapper/ssd-root                         /               ext4      noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro    0         1
UUID=8e645641-889d-4eec-b356-8fe90d683bf8    /boot           ext2      defaults                                0         2
/dev/mapper/ssd-swap_1                       none            swap      sw                                      0         0
/dev/mapper/hdd-storage                      /media/storage  ext4      noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro    0         1
/media/storage/home                          /home           none      defaults,bind                           0         0
/media/storage/var/log                       /var/log        none      defaults,bind                           0         0
```

EDIT: Setting the mount location from /media/* to /mnt/* solved this issue.

Comment: Nope, IMHO you can't

Comment: may i ask why you want to do that? i mean which is the point?

Comment: Is this an internal or external disk? If internal, this is a bug, like Blueberry says, but we don't know that until you give us that information. Please update your question...

Comment: @FranciscoTapia : I want to do that to prevent accidental unmounts while I press the unmount buttons of USB sticks that I've inserted.

Comment: well, as i know, u cant umount with that button if the usb stick is writting/reading

Comment: I apologize for not being more clear, but I was talking about my internal HDD unmount button, not the ones from the USB sticks.. those are fine and can stay :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per this [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=660595) gnome users were already facing it ,Hope there might be some fix around it soon

Now as of know you could change the mount point to /mnt/"something". Modify your fstab and it shouldn't show the unmount option any longer.

Then you may bind mount it to the directory you want:

```
UUID=your_uuid_here /mnt/DATA ext4       defaults        0       2
/mnt/DATA             /home/yrogirg/DATA   none bind 0 0
```

Comment: Yep, you're right.. it seems to be a bug with no solution in sight.. thanks for the answer though.

Comment: What is wrong with the above solution? Seems to work as expected. Is there any drawback of above?

Comment: The above solution works, that's why I marked it as the winning answer... I just set it from /media/ to /mnt/ and the button went away.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is ancient, but I still needed it today after reinstalling my OS:

As stated by BlueBerry in the accepted answer, I changed my mounting location from /media/storage to /mnt/storage and it works; the unmount button has vanished.

Shown below is my current /etc/fstab :

```
# Default filesystem setup
# <file system>                 <mount point>           <type>  <options>                                <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ssd-root            /                       ext4    errors=remount-ro,noatime,nodiratime     0       1
/dev/mapper/hdd-storage         /mnt/storage/           ext4    defaults                                 0       2
/dev/mapper/ssd-swap_1          none                    swap    sw                                       0       0

# Home directories
# <file system>                 <mount point>           <type>  <options>                                <dump>  <pass>
/mnt/storage/home               /home                   none    defaults,bind                            0       0
/mnt/storage/var/log            /var/log                none    defaults,bind                            0       0

# SSD tweak: temporary directories as tmpfs
# <file system>                 <mount point>           <type>  <options>                                <dump>  <pass>
tmpfs                           /tmp                    tmpfs   defaults,noatime,nodiratime,mode=1777    0       0
tmpfs                           /var/tmp                tmpfs   defaults,noatime,nodiratime,mode=1777    0       0
```

I hope this might help someone in the future.